# Display PHP JSON data with jQuery/AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

So I have this on the PHP side:

```
//enclosed in for loop start
$titleArray[] = $title;
$idsArray[] = $id;
//enclosed in for loop end
```

After the loop runs, the arrays are populated, here is a var_dump showing that. And then we json encode it and exit, sending it as a response for jQuery to handle.

```
var_dump($titleArray);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "T1"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "T2"
}

var_dump($idsArray);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "I1"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "I2"
}

$output = array('success' => true, 'type' => 'valid', 'titles' => ''.$titleArray.'', 'ids' => ''.$idsArray.'');
echo json_encode($output);
exit();
```

Here is where I run into the issue. I can't seem to access those arrays (titles/ids) anymore. The response is:

```
{"type":"valid","titles":"Array","ids":"Array"}
```

Here is the post success area to handle the response:

```
success: function(output) {
             var x = $.parseJSON(output);
                 if(x.type=='valid'){
                     $.each(x.titles, function(k, v) {
                         $("#output-area").append('<div id="'+v.ids+'" class="title">Title: '+v.titles+'</div>');
                     });
                 }
         }
```

2 new divs should be appended at this point, as there are 2 items in the arrays. Instead, I get 5 newly appended divs with undefined as the `v.ids` and `v.titles` values. How can I get the correct and desired output in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have pass `Array` to `json_encode()`

```
array('success' => true, 'type' => 'valid', 'titles' => $titleArray, 'ids' => $idsArray );
```

Comment: By taking off the commas around the $titleArray & $idsArray, I now get 2 divs instead of 5, as expected. However, the values are still undefined in the outputted divs.

Answer (score 1):

Create a single array

```
$data[] = array('id' => $id , 'title' => $title );
$output = array('success' => true, 'type' => 'valid', 'data' => $data );
echo json_encode($output);
exit();
```

in javascript

```
success: function(output) {
             var x = $.parseJSON(output);
                 if(x.type=='valid'){
                     $.each(x.data, function(k, v) {
                         $("#output-area").append('<div id="'+v.id+'" class="title">Title: '+v.title+'</div>');
                     });
                 }
         }
```

Comment: Really close! This fixes the undefined variable names, So far the only issue left is the output is all in one div like this `<div id="T1,T2" class="title">Title: I1,I2</div>` instead of outputting 2 unique divs

Comment: The jquery you posted in the comments does not work. Can you show what it would look like in your post on the PHP side? I am basically trying to remove the commas found here: `<div id="T1,T2" class="title">Title: I1,I2</div>` and creat a div for each.

Comment: `var sep = '';
    var ids =''; 
    var titles='';
    $.each(x.data, function(k, v) { 
        ids += sep + v.id;
        titles += sep + v.title; 
        sep = ","
     });
     $("#output-area").append('<div id="'+ids+'" class="title">Title: '+titles+'</div>');`

Comment: hmmm.. I still get the same exact output with the comma and 1 div instead of 2: `<div id="T1,T2" class="title">Title: I1,I2</div>`

Comment: \\Before Loop
`$sep ="";` \\in loop ` $ids .= $sep . $id;
        $titles .= $sep . $title;` \\ display `$output = array('success' => true, 'type' => 'valid', 'ids' => $ids,'titles' => $titles );
echo json_encode($output);
exit();
` \\and js  ` success: function(output) {
             var x = $.parseJSON(output);
                 if(x.type=='valid'){
                     $("#output-area").append('<div id="'+x.ids+'" class="title">Title: '+x.titles+'</div>');
                 }
         }      `

Comment: Final code `   var sep = '';
    var titles='';
    $.each(x.data, function(k, v) {
        titles += sep + v.title; 
        sep = ","
     });
     $.each(x.data, function(k, v) {
         $("#output-area").append('<div id="'+v.id+'" class="title">Title: '+titles+'</div>');
     });
     
                     ` this will create two div with diff id and same content

Comment: Again, same issue of 1 div being returned with a comma separated list of variables. I feel like we need to split the comma separated list and then loop over each separated variable. Just for reference, you can always edit your post directly to add/change code instead of the comments area so it doesn't become too long with code:)